# Image of a proper subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to solve this excercise:

> Let $f:A\to B$ a bijection. Then $X\subset A$, $X\neq A$ if and only if $f(X)\subset B$, $f(X)\neq B$.

I am trying to prove it by doing both directions and I think I've accomplished the sufficient condition; however, i cannot figure out how to prove the necessary condition. I think I should take an element $x\in B\setminus f(X)$ to show that it doesn't belong to $A\setminus X$ but I cannot understand how. Anyone could help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

choose $y_0\in B/f(X)$. By onto $\exists \;x_{0}\in A$ such that $f(x_{0})=y_{0}$. But $x_{0}\in A/X $ otherwise $f(x_{0})=y_{0}\in f(X) $(contradiction). So $A/X$ is nonempty and obviously $X\subseteq f^{-1}(B)=A$. Hence $X$ is proper subset of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

For the reverse implication, note that $g = f^{-1}:B \to A$ is also a bijection, and so you can use your proof for the forward implication applied to $g$.